# Mysql select on non linked tables

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables, that are not linked the standard way (I'm aware this isn't a good way to do it)

lets say the tables are setup like the below

Table: 
**component**

fields:
**cid, cname, rangeid, company**

Table: **ranges**

fields: 
**rid, rangename, year**

While this is quite simple in a relational DB, i'm not too sure of the cleanest way to do this otherwise (remaking the DB is not an option).

the basic query I need is.

```
select * from component where range.year = '2014' and company = 'xxx'
```

any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to filter by a filed in the other table without joining them.
Try:
   SELECT c.* FROM component c LEFT JOIN ranges r
    ON c.rangeid = r.rid
   WHERE r.year = '2014' and c.company = 'xxx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT a.cid, a.cname, a.rangeid, a.company, b.rid, b.rangename, b.year
FROM component a
JOIN ranges b ON
    b.rid = a.rangeid
WHERE b.year = 2014
    AND a.company = 'xxx'
```

**Result**

```
| CID |     CNAME | RANGEID | COMPANY | RID | RANGENAME | YEAR |
------|-----------|---------|---------|-----|-----------|------|
|   1 | Component |       1 |     xxx |   1 |     Range | 2014 |
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e230/2)

If a range from `component` may not exist in `ranges`, then use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

[`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the two tables:

```
select c.cname, r.rangename, r.year, ...
from component AS c
INNER JOIN ranges AS r ON c.rangeid = r.rid
where r.year = '2014' 
  and c.company = 'xxx';
```

**Note that:** You can `JOIN` any tables normally, even if they haven't any relation between them, just put the condition in the `ON` clause, just like in your case. But, you have to ensure that indexes are setup correctly, see this page fore more information:

- [Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` is what you are looking for :

```
select * 
from component 
inner join ranges on rid = rangeid and year = 2014
where company = 'xxx'
```